# Summary Of Sum Of Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have sql like below:

```
select 
count(*), sum(summary.imp), sum(summary.taps) 
from(
   select 
   sum(impressions) as imp, sum(taps) as taps 
   from report 
   where org_id = 1 and report_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-10-10'
   group by org_id, country, text)
summary;
```

This query creates derived temporary table in MYSQL. Is there a way to solve it with alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

I've read (but haven't tested) that MySQL supports multiple columns in a count distinct:

```
select 
  count(distinct org_id, country, text), sum(impressions) as imp, sum(taps) as taps 
from report 
where org_id = 1 and report_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-10-10'
```

I'd be interested to know if it's true. I'm also reasonably confident something like this would work:

```
select 
  count(distinct concat_ws('###', org_id, country, text)), sum(impressions) as imp, sum(taps) as taps 
from report 
where org_id = 1 and report_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-10-10'
```

Comment: Yes. I was doubting whether it supports multiple columns or not in COUNT(DISTINCT..) . But you are right. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` on a custom string made out of `org_id`, `country` and `text`. This would ensure that only unique combinations of them are counted (thus emulating GROUP BY and then COUNT).

I have used an arbitrary delimiter `&&`. If your `text` or `country` column can contain this delimiter, then you can use some other uncommon character combination as delimiter:

```sql
select 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(org_id, '&&', country, '&&', text)), 
  sum(impressions) as imp, 
  sum(taps) as taps
from report 
where org_id = 1 and report_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-10-10'
```

For good performance, define the following composite index on `report` table: `(org_id, report_date)`

Comment: Could you please suggest to me index for this query also?

Comment: @Sha I have given it in the last line of the answer :-)  "*For good performance, define the following composite index on report table: (org_id, report_date)*"

Comment: When I implement it, Explain shows; 18590030 rows and extra: using index condition. Is there a way to reduce it more with using more index?

Comment: @Sha No, I dont think you can use any other index here; because you have range condition on `report_date`. MySQL would simply stop at that column in the index.

Comment: Would it use an index if it was reliant on output of a concatenating function?

Comment: @CaiusJard It won't use index neither in your answer; nor mine. You can give it a try :-) MySQL would simply stop at the range condition in the index. Still, be my guest and give a try

Comment: @CaiusJard another thing to note is that MySQL needs to go into data tree anyway to compute sum on impressions etc. So it really does not make sense to use index for distinct operation. At the end of the day, it is all about minimizing query cost.

Comment: Yes, @MadhurBhaiya is right. I've just tried all of them one by one and It doesn't work. I think that the best solution can be summarize data according to date with new table.

Comment: I was merely curious, not critical; conceptually a query like this could be totally answered from

Comment: An index if the columns were in the right order/ it included relevant fields, but I'm not even sure if MySQL does that kind of thing